# SQL - Why does on delete set null results in cycle

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Why does a foreign key with option `ON DELETE SET NULL` can result in potential cycles?

I received the warning in SQL Server 2008 and do not understand it. 
It is clear for me that cascading operations may result in cycles but `SET NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

The [SQL Server docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186973(v=sql.105).aspx) says:

> **ON DELETE SET NULL**
>
> Specifies that if an attempt is made to delete a row with a key
>   referenced by foreign keys in existing rows in other tables, all the
>   values that make up the **foreign key in the rows that are referenced
>   are set to NULL**. All foreign key columns of the target table must be
>   nullable for this constraint to execute.

Comment: This just explains that the references are set to null but does not explains the potential cycle risk. I added an answer i thought of.

Answer (score 0):

It could lead to cycles if the column that holds the foreign key reference in a different row, itself is referenced by a foreign key constraint (e.g. references on non primary keys).

If only foreign key constraints on primary keys are used this should not be valid.